How to start a screen session from entrypoint shell script, and make it persist?
I am starting a screen session in my entrypoint shell script in docker, then log the output of screen -list to a file.
#!/bin/bash

screen -S my_screen -dm bash -c 'cd project && npm run start'

screen -list > scr_list.log

Then I connect to the docker container and see the outputted log.
here is a screen on: 
        14.my_screen      (12/18/24 17:55:29)     (Detached) 
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.

But when I manually run screen -list after connecting, it outputs:
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-root.

Using the same user (whoami): root
I currently have multiple screen services running inside the container and I manually restart individual ones from time to time whenever I make some changes in the container
Any ideas, what could be the issue please?
Update
screen seems to persist, but once I add npm run dev, the screen does not persist. When I run the same script from inside the container, it works.

You shouldn't need screen at all.  If your image's default CMD is npm run start, then you can see the docker logs of your container as part of the default setup.

If you really need screen, try this: screen -S my_screen -dm bash -c 'cd project && npm run start'; read -p 'press a key to quit screen >>> ' because screen stop after finishing I guess

@DavidMaze Can I restart these commands like screen from within the docker container please? I currently have multiple screen services running inside the container and I manually restart individual ones from time to time whenever I make some changes in the container

@GillesQuénot Thank you for your help, this does not seem to work however

Can you [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]?  What code have you written, what is in your Dockerfile, and why are you trying to run the program indirectly under screen rather than just running it as the only container command?

@DavidMaze Updated and with answer, thank you!

Try to add sleep 3 between screen -S... and screen -list >...

I figured out the issue: npm was not found.
As suggested in the comments, I used read -p to pause the script and found out eventually that screen was persisting, but got terminated.
Update
To add node and npm to your $PATH variable, without needing to know the version number, use:
source /root/.nvm/nvm.sh

Original solution
By running which npm I found the path to my npm installation (version), then added it to the $PATH in my script.
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/npm

(folder in which npm executable is located)
